# Code doesn't execute correctly the first time. Next time it does

Tags: javascript, html

I made some code to check if a value in the database is null or not.

Here is my code:

```
var tabel;
var running = false;
function CheckRunning(tabel){
this.tabel = "tabel"+tabel+"";
var db = window.openDatabase(this.tabel, "1.0", this.tabel, 1000000);
db.transaction(checkrunningDB, checkerrorCB);
console.log(this.running);
return this.running;
}

function checkrunningDB(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT max(id), sluttime FROM '+this.tabel, [], checkrunningSuccess, checkerrorCB);
}

function checkrunningSuccess(tx, results) {
    if (results.rows.item(0).sluttime != null){
        this.running = false;
    } else{
        this.running = true;
    }
}
function checkerrorCB(err) {
     this.running = false;
    console.log(err);
}
```

So i made a button, the runs this CheckRunning() function.

When i press it, i get this (each line represents a button click):

```
false
true
true 
true 
true
```

Comment: If you have a follow-up question, it is best to ask a new one instead of changing the title of your existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database functions are running asynchronously.  The callback, `checkrunningSuccess`, will be run when it is done, but the line after `db.transaction(checkrunningDB, checkerrorCB);` may execute before then.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. makes a lot of sense. Any specific solutions to my problem? Possible to make it run synchronously?
I would like to be able to do this: `if (CheckRunning('something')){//do something}`

Comment: It's not possible or recommended - most web APIs are designed event-driven or asynchronously.  An `openDatabaseSync` function is available to web workers but since they are already background tasks, blocking for a database transaction won't freeze the browser.

Comment: It's for a phone app (phonegap). Can i show a loading screen or something?

Comment: WebDB has an [asynchronous architecture](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#introduction).  You just need to adapt to it in your code.